# Spring framework. How to store some data to prevent each time access db

Tags: spring, session, caching, memory

I have in my application list of customers and users. I would like get the list of them only on start. Then use data that is stored locally, not from DB.

Can You advice me some methods with examples?

I think about HttpSession object? But I am not sure is it ok?
Cause this data should be available only for logged user, that access it on start.

List of customers will be available on each page off application!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Spring cache http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

You can annotate your repository methods:

```
@Cacheable(value="customer", key="#prsonalNum")
public Customer findCustomer(String prsonalNum) {
   ...
}
```

The application will enter the method body only the first time. After that the value will be taken from the cache.

You can also evict the cache when you update some customer for example.

```
@CacheEvict(value="customer", allEntries=true)
public void addCustomer(Customer cust)
```

Comment: Ok. In my `@Repository dao class` I have methods that do CRUD operation on db. How to update cache on that methods (add, update, delete)

Comment: Thank You for your comprehensive answer. I will dive into docs.

Answer (score 1):

For synchronizing insert and update operations with the cache use @CachePut annotation and for synchronizing delete operations with the cache use @CacheEvict annotation.

Use the same cache name (value paramter) and same key value

And you should enable caching with @EnableCaching annotation on one of your configuration classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the HttpSession object, however, only put it in the session once, the user has logged in... and you can remove it from the session on page close...

Comment: Ok, but how to check is that element in session already set. I would like to avoid multiplay operation: `session.setAtribute()`

Comment: us the getValue() on the session object, if you don't get anything then you know you have to set it... if you set the session object correctly, you should be okay...

Comment: `getValue()` is deprecated already. You should use `getAttribute()`. But this is still lack of some functionality like: **Auto update session values after some db updates on this data**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the data multiple times and do not want to query each time. i would suggested to create a simple Cache suing HashMap or HashTable.

You can easily save the list of customers across every id in such data structure.

and in spring you can easily create a singleton bean which will hold this hashmap and accessible across the application.

Comment: Why to create cache mechanism if there is already plenty solution done?